# Karma test for angular directive with window injected

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, google-closure-compiler, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a test for an angularjs directive. The directive calculates the height of an element in relation to the height of the window. 
The directive is written using the google closure style (I am new to this style of writing code, so please feel free to correct it).

The directive works fine but I am getting this error when running the test:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.link.bind(this)')
```

I have also not injected the window, not really sure how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The directive (which works):

```
(function(){
/**
    Constant, size of bottom padding.
 */
var PADDING_BOTTOM = 45;

/**
 * @constructor
 */
var Directive = function($window) {
    this.link = this.link.bind(this);
    this.$window = $window;

    this.scope;
    this.elem;
    this.attrs;
};

/**
 * Height Calculator directive factory. Entry point and used in `module.directive`.
 */
Directive.factory = function($window) {
    var dir = new Directive($window);
    return {
        link: dir.link
    };
};

/**
 * Linking function.
 */
Directive.prototype.link = function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var that = this;
    this.scope = scope;
    this.elem = elem;
    this.attrs = attrs;

    var w = angular.element(this.$window);

    // Created a function that can watch the
    // width of the window so we know when its changed
    this.scope.getWindowHeight = function () {
        return w.height();
    };

    // Watch for the size of the window changing
    this.scope.$watch(that.scope.getWindowHeight, function (newWidth, oldWidth) {
        var offset = that.elem.offset().top;
        var window_height = that.$window.innerHeight;

        var iframeHeight = window_height - offset - PADDING_BOTTOM;

        that.elem.height(iframeHeight);
    });

    // Capture the window event so we can capture window resize event
    w.bind('resize', function () {
        that.scope.$apply();
    });
};

app.directive('heightCalculator', Directive.factory);

})();
```

and this is the karma test:

```
describe('HeightCalculator directive', function() {


    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    }));

    it('should be the height of the window minus position on page minus padding bottom', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {

        var element = angular.element("<div height-calculator>test div</div>");

        $compile(element)($scope);

    }));
});
```

Comment: You don't need to inject `$window` on the tests. Probably the error came from that kind of directive creating which is the most horrible thing I have seen in years. That is what I call an excessive over complicated directive creation. I would try to do it like "normal" and it should work.

Comment: The directive itself works fine - but not the test.
I used to do it "like normal", however recently started reading about Google closure compiler – see: http://www.mircozeiss.com/a-radical-new-approach-to-developing-angularjs-apps/ and http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not your code. It is a defect, or a lack of functionality, with PhantomJS. For some reason, someone forgot to include `Function.prototype.bind`. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522

From what I have gathered, an [es5 shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) should do the trick.